# Can't check collision between a mask and a rect in pygame

Tags: collision-detection, pygame

I'm new to using masks in Pygame and I'm having trouble with them.
I have already learned how to check collisions between two masks but I'm wondering about an effective way to check collisions between a rect and a mask.

I've seen this post on stackoverflow : [collisions between rect and mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058750/how-to-check-collisions-between-a-mask-and-rect-in-pygame) but I didn't understand the answer and I don't even want to create my own function to do this work as I think there is a way to do it with the pygame functions.

So I tried to find a way myself and this is my attempt:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self) :
        self.x, self.y = 240, 300
        self.rect = Rect(self.x, self.y, 50, 50)
        # I have made a function to get the coordinates of the center of an image or a rect
        self.center = center(self.x, self.y, self.rect)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.Mask((50, 50), True)
        # some code

    def blit(self) :
        # update the pos of the center
        self.center = center(self.x, self.y, self.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(MyScreen, 'green', self.rect, border_radius=2)
        # some code

class Circle:
    def __init__(self) :
        self.image = load('redcircle.png')
        self.x, self.y = 400, 220
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.center = center(self.x, self.y, self.image)

    def blit(self) :
        # update the pos of the center
        self.center = center(self.x, self.y, self.image)
        MyScreen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

myrectangle = Rectangle()
mycircle = Circle()

collision_detection() :
    # I also created a function called 'offset' to calculate the offset
    # However I still don't understand what an offset is, that's why I'm just calculating it automatically
    if mycircle.mask.overlap(myrectangle.mask.get_rect(center=myrectangle.center), offset(mycircle, myrectangle)):
            print('it worked !')
```

This code didn't work And I got a "TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.mask.Mask, not pygame.Rect" error.

So now I'm looking for a simple way to detect collisions between a mask and a rect object and as I mentionned in the comments in the code above, I still don't understand what is an offset that the function `pygame.mask.overlap` takes though I also checked this [post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47694/meaning-of-offset-in-pygame-mask-overlap-methods).
So I'm looking for an easy explanation, thanks !

Comment: `overlap` appears to be taking a `Mask` as its first parameter, did you try to just pass `myrectangle.mask`?

Comment: @Vaillancourt, no but I'll try that !

Comment: @Vaillancourt, I can't believe it, it worked, thank youu. Please write your suggestion as an answer with some more details so that I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you create your "rectangle mask" seems appropriate and roughly in line with the question you've linked to on StackOverflow:

```
self.mask = pygame.mask.Mask((50, 50), True)
```

Now that this is out of the way, it seems that the [`mask.overlap` method](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap) that you use expects a `Mask`, not a rectangle. Since you have defined that "rectangle mask" in your `Rectangle` object, you just need to pass it to the other object's `overlap` method.

```
if mycircle.mask.overlap(myrectangle.mask, offset(mycircle, myrectangle)):
```

The `offset` the `overlap` method expects is only the difference in x/y between the two objects "top left" corners. In your example, I assume that the call to `offset(mycircle, myrectangle)` returns the difference

```
[myrectangle.x - mycircle.x, myrectangle.y - mycircle.y]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ;)